# I made a game with unity webGL and I published it on itch.io but it doesn't work

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, build, crash, publish

I don't know if it happens for some specific asset or for another motivation, but when I try to play the game it give me an error message

This is the game link https://konami-code.itch.io/escape-fish

Comment: Pleas post sufficient details here of the problem not just say there’s an error. As for example it doesnt error on my phone but not does it work

Answer (score 2):

I believe the the problem is you are using Unity version 2019.4.24f1, 2020.3.3f1 if you are. The only solution is to update to a newer version. this issue is fixed in version 2021.1.0a1 and onward. check out this website for more info: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/to-use-dlopen-you-need-emscriptens-linking-support-error-in-webgl-build.

Please next time, put some more effort into your questions. like adding the error from your game into the question. I'll cut you some slack because your new to stackoverflow.